# How to pass value between controller and config in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to pass variable to angular js config, 
This is my js app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'sasrio.angular-material-sidenav', 'ui.router']);
app.controller('baseController', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, $mdToast, $mdSidenav, ssSideNav) {
    $scope.menu = ssSideNav;
    $scope.getRequirment = function () {
        $http.get("site/requirment",
                {params: {dir: $scope.currentPath}})
                .then(function (response) {
                   return response.data;
                });
    };
    $scope.getRequirment();
});
app.config(['$mdThemingProvider', '$locationProvider', 'ssSideNavSectionsProvider', '$stateProvider',
    function ($mdThemingProvider, $locationProvider, ssSideNavSectionsProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('deep-orange')
                .accentPalette('deep-orange');
        ssSideNavSectionsProvider.initWithTheme($mdThemingProvider);
        ssSideNavSectionsProvider.initWithSections("Get getRequirment function in controller");
    }]);
```

How can I call a function in the controller from config?

I mean this line:

```
ssSideNavSectionsProvider.initWithSections("Get getRequirment function in controller");
```

Comment: You are configuring the `ssSideNavSectionsProvider`. Providers normally generate services, which you can inject into controller. Read more about providers [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Comment: This is why I hate angular materials theming. Just do it w/ CSS & abandon ship before you get too deep!

Answer (score 0):

There is a durty way to do this:

you can put this in your config

```
$rootScope.$watch("variable", function(n, o) {
// assign n value
})
```

and in your controller just set the

```
$rootScope.variable
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, controller executes in run phase, config in config phase.

I investigate source code a little, sections available as a service variable, you could try to add them from controller:

```
ssSideNavSections.sections.push(yourSection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set constant in configuration block and then access that constant via injecting it into controller.

Source: https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2017/04/what-when-and-how-angularjs-configuration-blocks/